# I cant import another file

Tags: import, pycharm, python-3.7

I can't import a file in Pycharm.

I use this code:

```
import useful_tools
```

This is the error:

> Unused import statement, this inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top level and class level items are supported better than instance items

Comment: Without providing any code is difficult. Just in case, try to do `import useful_tools as ut` and then use name ut.function() in order to access the library. This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means you did not uses `useful_tools` in the code after the import. It will work in runtime, but it's useless if PyCharm is not mistaken of course. Please provide the whole script code, as it's hard to tell more.